# How can I put a ttk.LabelFrame inside a ttk.PanedWindow?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm initiating in **ttk** and I keep getting this error while trying to add a LabelFrame inside a PanedWindow. Happens on **line 46** (`self.pwEntries.add(self.lfEntries)`):

> _tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!frame.!panedwindow.!panedwindow add window"

As I've no idea how to solve it I would really appreciate some help, please...

My code goes like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class CalcVendGame:
    def __init__(self, root):

        root.title("Calcula Venda Games")

        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
        self.mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.pwRoot = ttk.PanedWindow(self.mainframe, orient=VERTICAL)

        self.pwEntries = ttk.PanedWindow(self.pwRoot, orient=HORIZONTAL)

        self.lfEntries = ttk.LabelFrame(self.pwEntries, labelanchor='nw').grid(
            column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W))

        ttk.Label(self.lfEntries, text="Valor em Dólar de cada cópia:", padding="5").grid(
            column=2, row=1, sticky=E)
        self.CopiaEmDolar = StringVar()
        cpEmDol_entry = ttk.Entry(
            self.lfEntries, width=7, textvariable=self.CopiaEmDolar)
        cpEmDol_entry.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W)
        ttk.Label(self.lfEntries, text="Ex: \"19.99\"", padding="5").grid(
            column=4, row=1, sticky=W)

        ttk.Label(self.lfEntries, text="Quantidade de cópias vendidas:", padding="5").grid(
            column=2, row=2, sticky=E)
        self.CopiasVendidas = StringVar()
        cpVend_entry = ttk.Entry(
            self.lfEntries, width=7, textvariable=self.CopiasVendidas)
        cpVend_entry.grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W)

        ttk.Button(self.lfEntries, text="Calcular").grid(
            column=4, row=3, sticky=W)

        self.pwEntries.add(self.lfEntries)

        self.pwPC = ttk.PanedWindow(self.pwRoot, orient=HORIZONTAL)

        self.pwSteam = ttk.PanedWindow(self.pwPC, orient=VERTICAL)

        self.lfSteam = ttk.LabelFrame(self.pwSteam, padding=(
            5), text='Steam', labelanchor='nw')

        ttk.Label(self.lfSteam, text="Cut 35%", padding="5").grid(
            column=0, row=0, sticky=W)
        ttk.Separator(self.lfSteam, orient=HORIZONTAL)

        self.pwPatreon = ttk.PanedWindow(self.pwRoot, orient=VERTICAL)

        self.pwPC.add(self.pwSteam)
        self.pwPC.add(self.pwPatreon)

        self.pwMobile = ttk.PanedWindow(self.pwRoot, orient=HORIZONTAL)

        # self.pwRoot.add(self.lfEntries)
        self.pwRoot.add(self.pwEntries)
        self.pwRoot.add(self.pwPC)
        self.pwRoot.add(self.pwMobile)

root = Tk()
CalcVendGame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Also, this code give me no errors but results on a blank window:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

master = Tk()
mainframe = ttk.Frame(master, padding="3 3 10 10")

p = ttk.Panedwindow(mainframe, orient=VERTICAL)

# two panes, each of which would get widgets gridded into it:
f1 = ttk.Labelframe(p, text='Pane1', width=100, height=100)
ttk.Label(f1, text="Valor em Dólar de cada cópia:", padding="5")
f2 = ttk.Labelframe(p, text='Pane2', width=100, height=100)
ttk.Label(f2, text="Quantidade de cópias vendidas:", padding="5")
p.add(f1)
p.add(f2)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Examine `self.lfEntries`. It's not what you think it is. Then see the explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1101750/7432

Comment: @BryanOakley I think I got what you mean. Changing from `self.lfEntries = ttk.LabelFrame(self.pwEntries, labelanchor='nw').grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W))` to `self.lfEntries = ttk.LabelFrame(self.pwEntries, text='Pane1', labelanchor='nw', width=300, height=300)` and `self.lfEntries.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W))`, I got no errors but a blank window instead... None of the child widgets of `self.lfEntries` are showing up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to use any layout manager on the widgets.  Below is an updated code using `pack()`:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

master = Tk()

mainframe = ttk.Frame(master, padding="3 3 10 10")
mainframe.pack()

p = ttk.Panedwindow(mainframe, orient=VERTICAL)
p.pack()

# two panes, each of which would get widgets gridded into it:
f1 = ttk.Labelframe(p, text='Pane1', width=100, height=100)
ttk.Label(f1, text="Valor em Dólar de cada cópia:", padding="5").pack()
f2 = ttk.Labelframe(p, text='Pane2', width=100, height=100)
ttk.Label(f2, text="Quantidade de cópias vendidas:", padding="5").pack()
p.add(f1)
p.add(f2)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I'm using the `grid()` instead of `pack()`, but that was exactly what I was missing!!